# BufferedReader returns null second use

Tags: java, file-io

I'm using this custom class to simulate the `system.console` while debugging in eclipse.
What's confusing me is that `reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    System.in));` is returning null after the second called of `readLine`.

I thought it was because I had closed System.in, but according to [oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#close%28%29)

> The close method of InputStream does nothing.

So now I'm stumped. Here's the code:

```
public class CustomConsole {
    public String readLine(String format, Object... args) {
        if (System.console() != null) {
            return System.console().readLine(format, args);
        }
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        String line = null;
        try {
            System.out.print(String.format(format, args));
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    System.in));
            line = reader.readLine();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Logger.fatal(e.getMessage());
            System.exit(-1);
        } finally {
            if (reader != null) {
                try {
                    reader.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Logger.error("CustomConsole.readLine(): BufferedReader could not be closed");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                Logger.error("CustomConsole.readLine(): BufferedReader is null");
            }
        }
        return line;
    }

    public String readLine() {
        return readLine("", "");
    }

    public char[] readPassword(String format, Object... args) {
        if (System.console() != null) return System.console().readPassword(format, args);
        return this.readLine(format, args).toCharArray();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `close` method of `InputStream` does nothing, but `InputStream` can be subclassed and this subclass can implement `close` to be anything. This is the case with `BufferedInputStream` for example which, on my machine, is the type of `System.in`.

When you are closing your reader, you are closing all the underlying resources and therefore closing `System.in`. Nothing can then be read afterwards.

To solve this, you can simply remove the code that close the reader altogether, and it will work. It may seem odd to recreate a BufferedReader everytime, then just store it as a field of your `CustomConsole` and reuse it next time. Anyway you won't need to close it ever, since it is just a wrapper of a wrapper around System.in, which is handled by the system.

Rewriting your class in that spirit would produce something like this:

```
public class CustomConsole {

    private BufferedReader reader;

    public String readLine(String format, Object... args) {
        if (System.console() != null) {
            return System.console().readLine(format, args);
        }

        if (reader == null) {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        }

        try {
            return reader.readLine();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Logger.fatal(e.getMessage());
            System.exit(-1);
            return null;
        }
    }

// ....
```

Comment: Won't `BufferedReader` cause a leak at the end of my program's life if I never close it?

Comment: There are two things to understand: 1) All `close()` methods of standard Readers/InputStreams that are wrappers of another just close the underlying readers/streams. So only the last stream that use the system is actually worth closing. And since in your case it's System.in, this is already taken care of by the JVM.

Comment: 2) Anyway, at the end of your program, the JVM stops and the OS reclaims everything it was using, so there are actually never a resource leak at the end of a program, in the sense there are no program to hold a handle on the resource anyway anymore. It is just a good practice to close it in general, and is essential if you are creating a lot of short-term Readers in a long-running program.

Comment: If I was creating a lot of short-term Readers in a long-running program, would making `private BufferedReader reader` static help reduce overhead?

Comment: Sure, if you find there is a slowdown in that part of the code.

Answer (score 0):

InputStream is an abstract class. System.in will give you an object of a subclass of InputStream that may have the close method implemented differently.

How about modifying the class to have a field to hold the BufferedReader you create? Something like this:

```
public class CustomConsole {
    private BufferedReader reader;

    public String readLine(String format, Object... args) {
        if (System.console() != null) {
            return System.console().readLine(format, args);
        } else if (reader == null) {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                System.in));
        }

        return reader.readLine();
        ...
```

Add the exception handling code as you wish appropriate. You don't have to close the reader.